# Display textbox with associated label in a html table with radios

Tags: javascript, html-table, radio-button

My issue is really specific;
I'm building an html table and in each cell is a radio and several textboxes with buttons attached :

```
<td>
<br><input type="radio" name="testradio" id="radio1"><label for "radio1">Spline</label></br>
<br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl1" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl1" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl2" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl2" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl3" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl3" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
</td>

<td> 
<br><input type="radio" name="testradio" id="radio2"><label for "radio2">Polynome</label></br>
<br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl1" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl1" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl2" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl2" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl3" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl3" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
</td>
```

The texthide class is defined in my css as :

```
.texthide{
      display:none
}
```

I tried several JS without success here is how I want the html to work :
for each cell when the radio is activated the textboxes below have to be displayed (only these ones) below the radio ofc along with the attached buttons, alternative : how do I toggle on only the 1st textbox below the radio ?
When switching from one radio to the other the previously activated textboxes have to disappear and the one attached to current radio have to be displayed.
If possible I'd like a JS form that doesn't need to know the different radio or textboxes ids (basically just telling it when you activate a radio display all textboxes below it till next radio).

Any help will be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

your html:

```
<table class="mytable">
<tr>
<td>
<br><input type="radio" name="testradio" id="radio1"><label for "radio1">Spline</label></br>
<br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl1" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl1" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl2" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl2" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl3" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl3" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
</td>
<td> 
<br><input type="radio" name="testradio" id="radio2"><label for "radio2">Polynome</label></br>
<br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl1" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl1" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl2" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl2" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
<br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl3" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl3" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
</td> 
    </tr></table>
```

Your css stays as it was.

Your javascript:

```
$("input:radio").on("click", function(e){
    $(".mytable button").not(".texthide").addClass("texthide");
    $(".mytable input[type=text]").not(".texthide").addClass("texthide");
    var radio = e.currentTarget;
    $(radio).siblings("input").removeClass("texthide");
    $(radio).siblings("button").removeClass("texthide");
})
```

[Check it out on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/8/)

Please note this requires jQuery.

Edit: For the first you just do:

```
    $(radio).siblings("input").first().removeClass("texthide");
    $(radio).siblings("button").first().removeClass("texthide");
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I needed (just need some reformatting with padding on the table and I'm good to go) thanks. What about if I want to use the alternative way (i.e. display only the 1st textbox following the radio) ?

Comment: Edit should answer your question. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/9/

Comment: I'm validating your answer for you provided a solution without bringing any change to the html. Alex Oger's answer is pretty elegant though (even if applying a class to a div in the html will make it harder to restrain to only 1st textbox).

Comment: Yeah gotta agree its pretty elegant. I'm upping him for it.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it without JavaScript, just with some CSS, try something like that :

```
<td>
<br>
  <input type="radio" name="testradio" id="radio1">
  <label for= "radio1">Spline</label>
  <div class="blockhide">
    </br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl1" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for="spl1" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
    <br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl2" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl2" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
    <br><input type="text" name="splfit" id="spl3" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl3" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
  </div>
</td>

<td> 
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="testradio" id="radio2">
  <label for="radio2">Polynome</label>
  <div class="blockhide">
    </br>
    <br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl1" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl1" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
    <br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl2" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl2" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
    <br><input type="text" name="polyfit" id="spl3" value="0.00" class="texthide"><button for "spl3" class="texthide">Choose</button></br>
  </div>
</td>
```

and

```
.blockhide {
      visibility: hidden
} 

input[type="radio"]:checked + label + .blockhide {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/njhdC

Comment: Thanks a lot this works exactly as what I expected I now just have to choose between the 2 given methods :-). What about if I want to display only the 1st textbox directly following the radio ?